# How to use jQuery to switch divs on and off

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Okay so I am looking at this website, http://codetunnel.net/, and I saw that it only used one page, but jQuery was used to display different divs, therefore making it feel like a multipage website. I tried using the jQuery in my codepen, but it never worked. Can someone help me **understand** how the jQuery works, and how I can implement it into my own sites? The jQuery looks like this:

```js
$(function(){
$("#nav-home").click(function(){
 $("#home").show();
 $("#projects").hide();
 $("#contact").hide();

 $(".selected").removeClass("selected");

 $("#nav-home").addClass("selected");
});

$("#nav-projects").click(function(){
 $("#home").hide();
 $("#projects").show();
 $("#contact").hide();

 $(".selected").removeClass("selected");

 $("#nav-projects").addClass("selected");
});

$("#nav-contact").click(function(){
 $("#home").hide();
 $("#projects").hide();
 $("#contact").show();

 $(".selected").removeClass("selected");

 $("#nav-contact").addClass("selected");
});
});
```

https://codepen.io/orchtechnerd/pen/dRzGZV // my codepen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your code works.
Unfortunately, the visible div is covered by the #nav.
So the only thing you should do is add a "padding-top: 4em" style to the body.

Comment: Awesome! I can't believe I didn't see that. Thanks! I'll mark you as correct as soon as I can!